# Adding a new value into the linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I'm trying to implement function in linked list which will add a new note.
That new node is a sum of a previous and next node.

Here is my code, but i don't know where is mistake.

```
void change(Node *head){

    Node *p = head;
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->next = NULL;

    while(p != NULL){
        temp->data = p->data + p->next->data;
        temp->next = p->next;
        p->next = temp;
        p = p->next;
    }   
}
```

Comment: do you want to add the new node ah the head or the tail or else where ?

Comment: This should help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "_That new node is a sum of a previous and next node._" what next node a new node can have except if you add it not at head nor at end, but where do you add it them and under what condition ??

Comment: When you get to the end of the list `p->next->data` dereferences a null pointer

Answer (score 2):

If `head` is null, then this function allocates a new `Node`, but nothing points to the new node, so it will be leaked.

If `head` isn't null, but is the last (i.e. the only) node of the list, then `p->next->data` indirects through the null pointer, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Otherwise, in the first iteration, `p->next = temp; p = p->next;` makes `p` be the same as `temp`, and in the second iteration `p->next = temp;` makes the node point to itself, and the loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly after reviewing the code, the changes made do not persist after the function call.

```
void change(Node *head ){
```

to

```
void change(Node *& head ){
```

Pls try this.

Edit:-

There are other problems in the code as pointed out by others like 

1. Dereferencing a null pointer 
2. Invalid memory access.

Comment: not only that, when the list has only one element NULL is dereferenced in `p->next->data`, also nothing is done when the list is empty etc